# css class override property to use the value from another class

Tags: css, sass

I have two predefined classes (btn, fc-btn)

Both define the value for background-color and other properties:

```
.btn {
    background-color: red;
    ....
}

.fc-btn {
    background-color: blue;
    ....
}
```

Now I have an element that uses both classes:

```
<button class="btn fc-btn">Action</button>
```

Is there a way to make sure that the fc-btn background-color is ignored and the value from btn is used (regardless of selector hierarchy).

e.g. override the fc-btn property.

```
.fc-btn {
        background-color: unset/inherit/???;
}
```

Problem:
unset seems to also unset the value from btn
inherit does not work because btn is not a class of the parent but of itself

Comment: 
I know that I could just remove the background-color from the original fc-btn class, but it comes from an external library and I would rather override it

Comment: are the `two predefined classes` in the same file ? If yes then place the `.btn` definition below the `.fc-btn` . If it is in 2 different files then place the file which has the `.btn` definition after the file with `.fc-btn`.. So the general rule is the Definition which is read last will have the priority. .. Anybody correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new stlye with `.btn.fc-btn`

```
.btn.fc-btn{
  background-color: red;
}
```

or you can add `!important` to `background` in `.btn` style which is not recommended,

```
.btn {
    background-color: red !important;
    ....
}
```

Or If you can't modify CSS then set an inline style to the button

```
<button class="btn fc-btn" style="background:red">Action</button>
```

Comment: I do not want to specify the background-color myself, but rather force it to use the value of .btn

Comment: If you want to use `.btn` then remove `fc-btn` class from the `button` element

Comment: The fc-btn also contains other properties, so I need to keep both classes

Comment: hmm then there is no way without editing. Or if two classes from different CSS file then then move the `blue` css file to top and change the priority level

Answer (score -1):

@Chris In your css file place your ".btn " class below to ".fc-btn" class. A browser will automatically give priority to ".btn" class because it reads from the bottom.